# Prestashop SMTP Connection could not be established with host

Tags: smtp, gmail, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am having a problem configuring Prestashop SMTP.

I am trying to use gmail client.

1. SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
2. Username: xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
3. Password: password_of_gmail
4. SSL
5. 465

> Error: 
>   Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Cannot assign requested address #99]

Gmail has turn off 2 step vertification, POP3 enabled, and Allow less secure apps enabled too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your server doesn't allow external SMTP access.

For example 1and1 shared hosting doesn't allow that https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/816